# OBS Studio Node Streaming Settings

Tags: typescript, electron, obs

I am using StreamLabs OBS-Studio-node library for a sample project, I want to set use_auth for live streaming to Wowza server. This is my code

```
function setSetting(category, parameter, value) {
let oldValue;

// Getting settings container
const settings = osn.NodeObs.OBS_settings_getSettings(category).data;

settings.forEach((subCategory) => {
    subCategory.parameters.forEach((param) => {
        if (param.name === parameter) {
            oldValue = param.currentValue;
            param.currentValue = value;
        }
    });
});
console.log("Setting use_auth to true:", value);
// Saving updated settings container
if (value != oldValue) {
    osn.NodeObs.OBS_settings_saveSettings(category, settings);
}
}
```

I am setting the values like this

```
function udpateRtmp(window, settings) {
setSetting('Stream', 'server', settings.server)
setSetting('Stream', 'key', settings.key)
setSetting('Stream', 'service', 'custom')
console.log("test","Setting use_auth to true");
setSetting('Stream', 'use_auth', true)
setSetting('Stream', 'username', "mani")
setSetting('Stream', 'password', "Pr1th1v1")
return true;
}
```

use_auth is not working, unable to stream to wowza server with this method. In Wowza server when I disable authentication, then I am able to stream to the server.

I would like to know how to set the use authentication method in obs-studio-node?

Comment: "is not working" isn't terribly helpful in debugging your issue

Answer (score -1):

Challenging without a bit more info, but my next steps would be:

I would look at the Wowza logs to get a clue as to what is not working from that side.  I know Wowza support username/password auth

I would try from the OBS product itself and compare to the node outcome